# Objective of solution in original space during solution reading

Tags: c, scip

I read a solution in the original problem space during the INITSOLVE stage. Some multi-aggregated variables are ignored. I guess this is okay since their values can be inferred once other variables' values are fixed. However, the objective value of the read solution is now off.. since objective from those multi-aggregated variables are not included.. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

The objective coefficients of multi-aggregated variables are added to the variables of the active representation, so that the objective value of the solution should normally still be correct.

However, it can happen that the multi-aggregation was done by a dual argument, i.e., there might be solutions where the multi-aggregated variable is set to a different value, but you can still set it to the value given by the multi-aggregation without deteriorating the objective. Moreover, presolving might change bounds or fix variables based on this type of argument as well.

In this case, your solution might not "fit" into the presolved problem, but is "adjusted" to a solution with value not worse than your original solution. Is this the case? Is the objective value of the solution better?

Moreover, you should check the objective function value of the solution with SCIPgetSolOrigObj() in order to get the objective value in the original space, since the objective offset and factor can be changed during presolving.
Also, please check the values of the variables in the original problem to see how the solution differs from the one you read in.

Comment: Thanks, Gerald. I checked the values of the variables in the original problem, they are the same as the one read. However, when I call SCIPgetSolOrigObj(), it's still off. I also printed scip->origprob->objoffset at stage PRESOLVED, SOLVING, SOLVED, they are all zero. The final solution is correct though...

Comment: How far is the solution off? What are the objective value that you expect and the one that SCIP outputs?

Comment: As before, if I get objective from the read solution, objectives from multiaggregated variables are omitted. Let me add more details, the solution is kept as an independent solution, it's not added to the primal. I don't understand why objoffset is zero, and the final found solution has correct objective..